# How to hide bot Telegram token with gitignore?

Tags: python-3.x, github, gitignore, telegram-bot

On GitHub in the public domain is the code of my telegram bot, where is my token. I want to hide it, what should I do? I know that this should be done with gitignore

```
import telebot
import time
TOKEN = "872521057:AAF2Kx4Y3WC-cs................"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello")
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

If you want to deploy to Heroku, a better approach would be to use an environment variable.

Change:

```
TOKEN = None

with open("token.txt") as f:
    TOKEN = f.read().strip()
```

to:

```
import os

TOKEN = os.environ["TOKEN"]
```

Then, use the command `heroku config:add TOKEN=…` to set the environment variable.

To run your bot locally, use:

```
TOKEN=… python3 bot.py
```

I hope that helps!

---

## Original answer

`.gitignore` cannot be used to ignore lines of code, only whole files.

However, you could read the token from a file, and put *that* in your `.gitignore`.

Here's how I'd do it:

1. To be safe, first revoke your token by sending the `/revoke` command to [@BotFather on Telegram](https://t.me/botfather).
2. Put `token.txt` in your `.gitignore` and commit.
3. Create a file `token.txt` next to your bot code and put your
   new token in it.
4. After that, change the the line that says `TOKEN = …` to:

   ```
   TOKEN = None

   with open("token.txt") as f:
       TOKEN = f.read().strip()
   ```

   This will read the `token.txt` file you created earlier, and store
   it in the `TOKEN` variable, so your token stays private.

Comment: Please explain me how to put token.txt in .gitignore? Thanks for your answer)

Comment: @ИванИванов you can just append `token.txt` to the end of your .gitignore.

Comment: i deployed my bot on Heroku and in the logs Heroku writes that  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No suc
h file or directory: 'token.txt'

Comment: @ИванИванов I updated my answer. I hope that helps, it should work. :)